Fantasy book with king/father who pretends to be insane
This book had to be written sometime before the 80's I'm pretty sure. It involves a king who has to pretend to be insane or at least incredibly foolish. He has three daughters and they each behave very differently with the coming crisis (some enemy on the march). I seem to recall one princess summoning a hero via a mirror? Another one summoned a science fiction hero with some ray gun.
At the very end of the book or series, when everything is revealed, the father says to his daughters something like, "I trusted each of you to do the right thing."

The setup with a king and 3 daughters being forced to run the kingdom makes me think of Shakespeare's King Lear. Gotta wonder how much that story borrowed from it.

@T.E.D. I actually assumed that this was King Lear and was wondering about someone querying Shakespeare here.

There's also the Bible. No daughters running the kingdom, but David has to pretend to be insane for a time to survive among the Philistines (see 1 Samuel 21)

This is Stephen Donaldson's Mordant's Need duology. First book is The Mirror of Her Dreams, second book is A Man Rides Through.
It starts with a woman being summoned from our world by an incompetent apprentice's flawed mirror to the kingdom of Mordant, where mirrors are magic - craft a mirror and it shows, not a reflection, but a scene from somewhere else, which can be used to travel to remote locations and bring things through, even if they're in another world. Besides Terisa, the main character, another summoned person is a warrior from a science-fictional world, with power armor and energy weapons.
Mordant's king, Joyse, is apparently senile, and a great crisis is brewing, with war on the horizon. There is a ton of scheming and politicking going on among people fed up with his seeming incompetence and poor leadership. Terisa comes to wonder about Joyse's behavior and just how much of it is real and how much is an act.

It'll be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180613/novel-boy-creates-summon-girl-they-fell-in-love/

Albeit not one that we would close as a duplicate because there's no accepted answer.
